# Почему возвращается значение из цикла, а не функции

Tags: javascript

```js
function partitionOn(items) {
  let arr = [];
  let long = 0;
  for (i=0; i<items.length; i++){
    if (items[i]%2===0){
      arr.push(items[i])
      items.splice(i,1)

    }
  }
  long = items.length;
  items = items.concat(arr)
  console.log(items)
  return long
}

var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var i = partitionOn(items);

console.log(items)
```

Почему в `items` элементы в цикле удаляются, а конкатенация не проходит ? В самой функции консоль выводит правильно, а вне ее массив как до конкатенации.

Comment: потому что вы `long` объявляете раньше, чем массив увеличиваете

Comment: @ThisMan а `long` то здесь при чем?

Comment: @teran вроде в заголовке про результат функции, а именно про `long`

Comment: замените `concat` на какой нить `Array.prototype.push.apply(items, arr);` и вернет нужное, иначе создается копия массива при присваивании

Comment: console.log() внутри функции выводит массив items таким как он должен быть[1,3,5,2,4,6], а вот снаружи остается все как до конкатенации [1,3,5]. Вопрос не про long был, это я кусок функции вырезал.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что `items.concat(arr)` возвращает другой референс на новый массив. Вы просто перетираете референс на массив входного параметра функции. Вам нужно либо манипулировать входным массивом, либо возвращать новый:

```js
function partitionOn(items) {
  let arr = [];
  let long = 0;
  for (i=0; i<items.length; i++){
    if (items[i]%2===0){
      arr.push(items[i])
      items.splice(i,1)

    }
  }
  long = items.length;
  items = items.concat(arr); // тут создали новый массив,
                             // присобачили к нему items и следом arr,
                             // вернули реф на новый массив
  
  return items;
}

var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var newItems = partitionOn(items);

console.log(newItems)
```